# Export a sass variable that have a css variable value

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm trying to export a sass variable that has a css variable value to my react component, and I'm receiving the wrong value, with the codes is easier to understand.

Here is my sass code:

```
$test: var(--color);
:export {test: $test}
```

My css variable:

```
:root {
--color:#fc4c02;
}
```

And my JS code:

```
colors={{
            active: {
            base: colors.test
            }
        }}
```

My base color instead of having the --color value comes as a string var(--color), someone can help me please?

Comment: May I ask - Why are you using sass variable when you can directly use css variable ?

Comment: I use this test value in other places too, other stylesheet files, and I wanto to use it on my javascript too, so if I have to change it value i can change only in one place, the root file can change too so I want to reference all my app styles to just the test variable, to use it on other stylesheets it works fine, but to export it to JS I have this problem.

Comment: you can just do  `base: 'var(--color)' ` in your JS and it would work as well